# Run a cuda file using terminal / IDE

Tags: cuda, gpu, sublimetext3, nvcc

I have a test.cu cuda file which I want to run and compile.
Following are the things that I tried.

1. Build a cuda build system in sublime-text 4

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "nvcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ${file_path}/${file_base_name}",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "selector": "source.cu, source.lib, source.exp",
    "path": "/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin",
    "shell": true
}
```

However, after compiling test.cu with the above system. I got

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory
[Finished in 6ms with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: nvcc test.cu -o test && /home/name/My Data/Code Repo/Geometric Learning/test]
[dir: /home/name/My Data/Code Repo/Geometric Learning]
[path: /home/name/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

2. compile using terminal

```
nvcc test.cu -o test
```

which generates `a.out` and `test`.
after this I ran

```
test
```

Which returned nothing.

How can I compile and run the code (preferably in sublime text)?

System Specifications: nvcc 10.1 + ubuntu 20.04 os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the ways by which one can compile .cu file

1. terminal

```
$ nvcc test.cu 
$ ./a.out
```

2. sublime build system

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "nvcc \"${file_path}/${file_name}\" && ./a.out && rm a.out",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "selector": "source.cu, source.lib, source.exp",
    "shell": true
}
```